# Execution of ScheduledExecutorService on multiple servers

Tags: java, websphere, scheduledexecutorservice

I've an ear that will be deployed on multiple servers as back-end ear. In that ear i need to add ScheduledExecutorService to fetch some records from database at certain time and process them. But i need to handle that only once not on all servers that the ear will be deployed on. Is that achievable using ScheduledExecutorService only on java8? or do i need to use another library that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService` is an interface defined by Java SE. It does not specify any requirements for implementations to build in awareness of or coordination across application servers.  Even the `javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService` interface, which is defined by Java EE, does not have any requirement for awareness/coordination of scheduling across different application servers, and thus the implementation that is currently provided by WebSphere Application Server does not currently provide this ability.  However, there is another technology within Java EE which does provide this capability: Persistent EJB Timers.  See the [linked knowledge center article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html) as a starting point for WebSphere Application Server traditional.  If you are using WebSphere Application Server Liberty, the capability is currently more limited and lack the ability for task execution to fail over across servers if the one assigned to run it goes down. There is currently a Request for Enhancement open against Liberty for this.